How to specify new current directory in shell script started by systemd?
I start /home/bernard/p1meter/getdate.sh script from terminald that crash on first cd command script (line 3 in script) !
#!/bin/sh
pwd 
cd /home/bernard/p1meter

I added pwd linux command to know what is my current directory when script run. Is is '/' (see in journalctl result)
Script is started using followed systemd command
sudo systemctl start getdata.service

The shell script start but is crashing on first cd command
In journalctl result, I can read following lines
The job identifier is 23045.
Dec 10 08:47:40 raspberrypi sh[20217]: [49B blob data]
Dec 10 08:47:40 raspberrypi sh[20217]: /
Dec 10 08:47:40 raspberrypi sh[20217]: /home/bernard/p1meter/getdata.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to /home/bernard/p1meter

Why my script doesn't find /home/bernard/p1meter directory ?
When I'm connected as bernard, ls /home/bernard/p1meter command work correclty !
bernard@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /home/bernard/p1meter
data  getdata.py3  getdata.service  getdata.sh
bernard@raspberrypi:~ $

The getdata.service config's file used by systemd contains followed lines
[Unit]
Description=Start extraction of P1 meter data

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/bernard/p1meter/getdata.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


What does getdata.service look like ?  Specifically what user and group (if any) are set in that file?

ProtectHome=?

I added requested information by davidgo

@Kamil: but what is the solution to explicitely specify a current directory that is normally in /home/bernard where bernard is a user directory ?

Could you run mount or findmnt to check whether either /home or /home/bernard are on a different filesystem?

I run mount and findmnt and I don't find any reference to 'home'. So I think that both directory are in same filesystem !? My installation is a simple Raspberry.

In that case, could you make the script run ls -la /home to check whether it gets at least that far? Second, does your text editor show the line endings mode when editing the script? Finally, what does the weird 1st log message really have if you add the -a option to journalctl?

@grawity: using -a I have seen some ^M on my shell script lines that represent \r ! My script is written on Windows using Notepad++ and is copied to Linux using pscp command of putty. I have executed dos2unix command on shell script and all is working now correctly. Thanks
